# Is it safe to delete branches by removing /refs/heads/review/* in git?

Tags: git, gerrit

I am using `Gerrit` and I quite often download changesets by doing `git review -d change-#`.  This leaves a ton of branches of the format `review/user/topic`.

Is it safe to remove these directly by doing `rm -rf .git/refs/heads/review`.  I know I can get the commits back from `Gerrit` but I don't want to corrupt the local repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by "safe".

Removing those branch head files won't corrupt the Git repository.  But if some review branches have been "packed" (and are now in `.git/packed-refs`), it won't delete those branch heads either.  If that qualifies as "safe", then yes, it's safe. :-)  (It also won't delete any reflogs for these references, and that's worse in a way, as those reflogs may then protect the review request items from being GCed.)

A better method is to use `git branch -D` on each `review/user/topic`, which will delete the reference `refs/heads/review/user/topic` and any associated reflog, regardless of whether the branch has been packed.  To enumerate these topics, use `git for-each-ref`:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/review | xargs git branch -D
```

for instance.

Comment: `git for-each-ref`.  Very cool.

By the way, you are missing a closing quote in your one-liner.  I tried to edit it but edits need to be at least 6 characters.